# How to convert Rails whole application in erb to haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, erb

I have one Rails application and all files are in `erb` format. Is there any quick way to convert whole application's `erb` file to `haml`.. without any conflict.

And also would like to know for the Reverse..

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: See this http://html2haml.heroku.com/ or this https://github.com/dhl/erb2haml

Comment: i dont want to do it manually

Comment: Then try that gem which i suggested.

Comment: and what about the reverse haml to erb...???

Comment: You won't like this, but we just did it manually - it's the best way to ensure efficiency & robust code :)

Comment: No problem - did you convert it in the end?

Comment: Frankly speaking I am very much impressed with you... in 24 u get this much reputations and be the expert in rails.. how?? :D I am surprised.. Great Achievement bro...heads of

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **erb-to-haml**

You can use from the command line html2haml

```
html2haml your_erb_file new_haml_file
```

If you want to convert all your files in one go, look at this article : http://shifteleven.com/articles/2008/06/08/converting-erb-to-haml-snippet

`erb2haml gem` will do the trick.. have a look to https://github.com/dhl/erb2haml

For **haml-to-erb**

I recommend you [HAML2ERB](http://haml2erb.herokuapp.com/) service . It's really cool and generates valid ERB/HTML code! Tested on big HAML views (over 800 lines of markup) from the real production app. Project active :)

have a look to this also http://makandracards.com/makandra/544-convert-haml-to-erb

Comment: `erb2haml` doesn't convert `haml` to `erb`.It converts `erb` to `haml`.

Comment: thnks... it's my mistake to write